# how to create vuetify like chip group with only html and css

Tags: html, css

How to create chip groups like [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chip-groups/#filter-results) with only html and css?
I tried but unable to do it

like this:
[image]

What I have now:

```html
<div class="chips-group">
   <div class="single-chip"  >
      <label :for="chip">
          <input type="checkbox" name="filter" :id="chip" value=""/>
          <span>chip</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to remove the checkbox default style. then style the span of the chip, and finally use the `+` css selector to style every `span` of chip that is placed  immediately after a checked chip to style its checked behavior.

```css
#chip{
-webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.chipBody{
border-radius:100px;
background-color: #fff;
border:1px solid #b5b5b5;
padding: 5px;
}
#chip:checked + .chipBody {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="chips-group">
   <div class="single-chip"  >
      <label :for="chip">
          <input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="chip" value=""/>
          <span class="chipBody">chip</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can add the little ✓ using `:before` pseudo element (with some more style):

```css
#chip{
-webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.chipBody{
border-radius:100px;
background-color: #fff;
border:1px solid #b5b5b5;
padding: 5px;
}
#chip:checked + .chipBody {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
#chip:checked + .chipBody:before {
  content:'✔';
}
```

```html
<div class="chips-group">
   <div class="single-chip"  >
      <label :for="chip">
          <input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="chip" value=""/>
          <span class="chipBody">chip</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rey you're  welcome! see the update for the check mark

Comment: and how to add and remove icon on select

Comment: @Rey `#chip:checked + .chipBody:before {
  content:'✔';
}` see the updated answer

Comment: adding a transition on background color would be perfect

Comment: @becem this is only a basic example. you can modify it however you want